# emacs: Does HideShow work with xml-mode (sgml-mode)?

Tags: xml, emacs

I use hideshow.el in my cc-mode buffers to collapse sections of the file I'm not looking at.

It would be nice to be able to do that in an XML doc.  I use emacs 22.2.1 and the built-in sgml-mode for xml editing.  I haven't gotten hideshow to work with the XML.  I mean, I turn on the minor mode but the keystrokes have no effect.  Ooh, except, I did get an XML comment to collapse.  But no elements.

Has anyone done this successfully?
Recommendations?

---

**EDIT**:  I'll bet it would work if I added an sgml-mode element to hs-special-modes-alist.   I'd need a regexp for start-block.  Has anyone done this?

---

I haven't moved to nxml-mode.  Should I?  does it do "folding" or hiding?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering my own question... I am using something like this.  Seems to work.

```
;; Fix XML folding
(add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
             (list 'nxml-mode
                   "<!--\\|<[^/>]*[^/]>"
                   "-->\\|</[^/>]*[^/]>"
                   "<!--"
                   'nxml-forward-element
                   nil))

;; Fix HTML folding
(dolist (mode '(sgml-mode
                html-mode
                html-erb-mode))
  (add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
               (list mode
                     "<!--\\|<[^/>]*[^/]>"
                     "-->\\|</[^/>]*[^/]>"
                     "<!--"
                     'sgml-skip-tag-forward
                     nil)))
```

Comment: Works great: could you somehow merge this into the next Emacs release?

Comment: `/` is valid character for XML attribute value. So `START` regex may break some XMLs, for example if attributes holds base64 data ((.